# How to use an Adobe Illustrator generated SVG including bitmapped image as a link with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, svg, bitmap

This took me a while to figure out, so I will describe it here for other interested parties:

I wanted to replace my web portfolio images (I'm a designer) with SVG's, so that file sizes would be reasonable and at the same time the images would look good on high-definition screens.

Many of my images have some bitmapped parts and some vector parts so it is essential to combine the two into a single SVG.

There were three main issues I ran into:

1) **SVG's exported from Illustrator lose their bitmap art when displayed using the `<img>` tag in an HTML page.**

2) **When using SVG's with an `<object>` tag, mouse events like onclick no longer work.**

3) **When using SVG's with an `<object>` tag, iOS on iPad would not scale the images correctly**. Only the container would be resized -- the actual image would stay the same.

Comment: 1. Convert the bitmap into a data URL and embed the image data it in the SVG. 2 use pointer-events:none to fix that. 3. Report that as a bug to the product's bugtracker.

Comment: That would work, but I am attached to loading bitmapped images separately for speed reasons -- I want the vector part of the SVG to load quickly and separating bitmapped images makes the SVG files much smaller. What I ended up doing is just using inline SVG code instead of the image tag -- separate bitmaps work fine in that case.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use **SVG's with embedded bitmapped images** (Illustrator files with placed PNG images, for example) I had to use:

```
<object data="yourimage.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

There is a known bug in WebKit ([Google Code report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234082)) that prevents SVG's in `<img>` tags from displaying a bitmapped component.

In order to **capture mouse events in an SVG**, I opened the Illustrator SVG itself and added a new line just before the `</svg>`:

```
<rect id="mynewobjectid" onclick="top.myjavascriptfunction(evt)" 
cursor="pointer" pointer-events="visible" fill="none"
width="1536" height="1536"/>
```

I got the width and height from the `<svg>` tag in the 5th line of the SVG, but this time I did not add "px". I don't think it would make a difference.

The **pointer-events="visible"** is necessary so that the empty rectangle captures mouse events.

The javascript function in the html document looks like this:

```
function myjavascriptfunction(evt){alert(evt.target.id)}
```

The result is a beautiful image that looks like a link and gives me an alert with the object ID when I click on it.

Note that I also changed the cursor to a hand so that the linked image would be visible as such, using `cursor="pointer"`

Thanks to [David Dailey](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/intro/partf_b.html) for his simple, working solution.

**[update about iOS problems]** It turns out that by default, iOS 7.0 on iPad refuses to resize the `<object>` tags correctly (it resizes the object boundaries, but not the enclosed image).

**The solution was to change the width and height in the SVG tag at the beginning of the SVG file to 100%, from their original pixel values.** Example at [ozake.com](http://ozake.com)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234082 is not a bug, it's desirable functionality to protect your privacy and as such I imagine Chrome would be unlikely to change to allow it. Firefox certainly won't for instance.

Comment: That thread seems to have died. Can you explain how it protects my privacy to prevent me from loading images in SVG if they're on the same server as the SVG code and the host HTML file?

Comment: Open redirectors make the same server guarantee meaningless.